# CodeIgniter "sess_time_to_update" and Indy Cookies

Tags: php, delphi, codeigniter, cookies, indy

I have this [horribly stripped delphi code](http://pastebin.com/iU8LqiuF) that basically login to server, save cookie in a **global** cookie manager, then upload files in threads (using Delphi 2010 + Indy 10.4736)

Each thread reads the **global cookie manager** and upload the file. Server side, I'm using PHP with **CodeIgniter**.

Everything works just fine, except that CodeIgniter has this **sess_time_to_update** setting in config.

This *sess_time_to_update* defaults to 300 seconds after which CodeIgniter [completely regenerate the session id](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/119256/).

This is **good** for security, but this also invalidates my login/cookie info in indy.

My question is: how can I avoid this **without** adjusting *sess_time_to_update*? Is there some setting in Indy to make it aware of the session id? Should I add a timer and automatically re-login every 300 seconds (or less)? What's the best approach to make Indy handle this situation?

Thanks!

**EDIT** FWIW: the global cookie manager contains [something like this](http://pastebin.com/WvwZhTTa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When CodeIgniter generates a new session, it should include the session ID in the cookies for each response it sends. Update your global cookie list so that subsequent requests will use the new ID instead of continuing to use the original value.

Comment: I have no pb accessing the **old** session id (from the global cookies manager), but I couldn't find the **new** session id in the response (ie. `IdHTTP.Response.RawHeaders.Text`). Do you mean I should send the new session id from the PHP script?

Comment: If CodeIgniter is changing session IDs and expects a prolonged session to be able to remain open, then it needs to send the new session ID back to the client somehow, or else there would be no point in changing the ID; it could just expire the session entirely instead. Cookies are the usual way of sending that kind of information to the client. How else are you notified of the change?

Comment: Yes I **know** that but as I said I couldn't find the **new** session id, neither in `Indy.Response` nor in Indy's `CookieManager`. So Unless I re-login **or** explicitly send the session id again the cookie manager will stick with the old session id

Comment: OK, it turned out that messing with IdHTTP.Request.RawHeaders to add cookies caused indy not to handle cookies correctly. I removed that code and made sure the global cookies manager was updated and now everything is OK